# Parse doesn't work ios 7

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

My app crash when i run on iOS7 device !

So i tried :

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_8_0
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
#else
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert   )];
#endif
```

iOS 8 Device is correct  but iOS 7 Device the push notification no working :(

any ideas?

Note:

I have the code  of another app  i used:

```
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

but now is not working

Comment: What does it say when it crashes in the log?

Comment: the log crash was when i used this : registerUserNotificationSettings:  for ios 7 but with  the if now is working without crash but ios7 device dont received the notifications and ios8 device is working very good

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code for a current app of iOS 7 and it is working fine. 
In `ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` write the same as you have written before.

```
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

Don't forget to add this to your `AppDelegate`

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

It is hard to know what you're missing in the code without the log message however my guess is that you didn't register user for notification settings. Cheers!

Comment: I don't have log message but i was missing the RegisterUserNotificationSettings but i added it and try again and my iphone with ios7 don't received the notification and another iphone with ios 8 received the notifications here my code http://pastebin.com/r71LHgvC